# How to create additional css tabs with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, tabs

I am trying to add addtional tabs whenever a new item is added to the database it is supposed to show on the webpage and display the new item without having to go into the code just having to add to the database i tried `$_GET` variable to try id but that did not work.

CODE:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($pages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <a href="?id=<?php echo $pages['id']; ?>"><label for="tab1"><?php echo $pages['name']; ?></label></a>
    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <p><?php echo $pages['content']; ?></p>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS CODE:

```
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px; 
  span { 
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;  
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 21px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: $tabs-base-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; 
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in-out);
    &:hover {
      background: darken($tabs-base-color, 10);
    }
  }
  .tab-content{
    z-index: 2;
    display: none; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 25px;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    left: 0; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
   }
   //The Magic
   [id^="tab"]:checked + label { 
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 17px; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15); 
   }
   [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
    display: block;
   }
   }
   p.link {
   clear: both;
   margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
   a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
    &:hover {
  background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 20);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying the PHP and SQL Query are not fetching any results when you go to a page like example.php?id=5

Comment: they are but they are not showing on the plain page

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem then.  If the sql is returning results, what problem are you having?  A problem with the CSS formatting, or a problem with the PHP?

Comment: i am having a problem with php i am trying to display all item out of mysql database and when you click on them the content displays

Comment: Multiple `div` with the same `id="tab-content"` are against html rules, and do you really want to loop the `ul` ?

Comment: ok but still don't answer the question

Comment: no i don't i just want to loop the li

Comment: Can you post a URL where this code is functioning?  Right now you have several problems with your code and markup, your sql query is only going to return one result, the tab IDs are all going to be "tab1", your results aren't going to be nested in the same ul, and you have no javascript to actually do the content display.  Forgive me when I say your attempt seems poorly researched.  It would be helpful if you had a specific problem or could provide more information like a link or scheenshot to the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id ='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($pages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <a href="?id=<?php echo $pages['id']; ?>"><label for="tab1"><?php echo $pages['name']; ?></label></a>
    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <p><?php echo $pages['content']; ?></p>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Try This Code not sure but try..